# Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, pipeline

I am trying to execute a script on multiple VM(2 servers for now) from Azure devops pipeline. Invocation of script is being done via  Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand.

**My issues**: on first VM command is executing without any issues. But on second VM, I am getting below error:

---

2019-07-21T08:35:00.5804498Z ##[error]Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command.
**ErrorCode:** Conflict

**ErrorMessage**: Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command.

**StatusCode**: 409

**ReasonPhrase**: Conflict

### **OperationID** : a7f0e50a-4f53-4d3b-84bf-35b7637d6df0

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: You could try the method, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10409#issuecomment-447421658

Comment: The suggested scripts(disable.cmd and enable.cmd) are not available for me at given location.

Comment: Do you always get this error? What's the result if you call that command on local machine?

Comment: Thanks all. Looks like after server reboot issue is fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Looks like one of the VM had some hung processes. When I rebooted both VMs, the VM which had issue generated an output file before restart.

Post restart, I am not getting the same issue again. Please look from this angle also If you are facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @starianchen-MSFT :)

Answer (score 2):

## Restart or Wait for 2hrs to timeout

You can restart the server if possible, or you can wait 2hrs to timeout the session.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this problem- although I had no other pipelines running simultaneously and my VMs in azure all appeared fine- I went ahead and did a restart on all in the resource group that would be affected. When I verified their restart succeeded, I re-ran the pipeline without issue.

"Did you try turning it off and on again?"

```
                -Moss (The IT Crowd)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** you can see what commands is executed in Azure portal below, then you can cancel the running command.

**Solution 2:** directly shutdown your VM, then start it and try to run commands again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well- I ran into this- and it was happening because I had 4 pipelines- and I was kicking them off manually, simultaneously. They each had a restore DB action that was trying to happen at the same time.

Only kick off your pipelines that restore DBs on the same VMs one at a time.